# How to set and lock Console size and position?

Tags: c#, console-application

I need help creating an application with a locked window size. I can set the size but not lock it or change the position.
Also, the solution could be is to make the command that sets the window size run at the same time as everything else.

**This is the code I have:**

```
using System;

namespace WindowSizeSetter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to start fullscreen.");
            Console.Read();
            SizeOfScreen();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void SizeOfScreen()
        {
            Console.SetWindowSize(172, 41);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# - Is there a way to make a fixed (height/width) console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062219/c-sharp-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-fixed-height-width-console)

Comment: This does help me a little but it doesn't make it fullscreen. It fixes it but it's not fullscreen. Also, it would be helpful if there was an answer to how to run more commands at the same time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423085/c-sharp-full-screen-console I suggest you to just set it to max size of window you are in. Don't forget you can dock console in windows 7/10 so the feature you want is obsolete.