# Console.Writeline working on x86 but not x64

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, console.writeline

I'm testing a project in visual studio 2012.

When I run my code in x86, `Console.Writeline` shows up in the output window. However, when I run it in x64, it does not.

I understand I can use `System.Diagnostics.Debug` instead, but I would really like to understand why `Console.Writeline` is not working, or if there is a setting somewhere.

Thanks.

**Edit:** An observation: The Visual Studio hosting process is disabled for both builds. When I enable it, all `Console.Writeline` messages show up for both x64 and x86. When I disable it again, only the x86 displays `Console.Writeline`.

Comment: Some info about what happening? Errors or smth?

Comment: No errors, normal functionality of the software, just Console.Writeline not showing up in output window. If I clean everything and re-build in x86... it works. When I got back to x64 it doesn't work. Very strange.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the hint. For me, enabling the hosting process did the trick, even though i'm still on vs2010. Still, the question remains why that should make the difference.

Comment: Using VS 2013 and experiencing the same stuff. Makes sense that the hosting process serves as a tunnel from your app to the VS Output window, but no idea where the difference between x86 and x64 comes from

Answer (score 3):

There should be no difference between the two.  Most likely you have a configuration difference between your x86 and x64 compilation profiles.  Check to make sure that you are building a console application in both cases.

Comment: You don't need to be making a console application to use `Console.WriteLine`, if you call it from any project type it *should* show up in the [Output Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hk6fby3.aspx).

Comment: This is true, but `Console.WriteLine` _won't_ show up in an application console window if you run the application outside of Visual Studio.  Which is what the question was about, as I understood it.

Comment: Well, both my x64 and x86 builds disable the visual studio hosting process. However, the x86 still displays console messages. If I enable hosting process, the x64 does as well. I am just trying to understand why there difference between unhosted x86 and x64 builds.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you copy settings from AnyCpu while creating x64. I had a similar problem but once I copied it, it worked fine.